# Merging Excel Data

Tags: excel, merge

I have a couple large spreadsheet in a Excel 2013 workbook.  The sheets have the same columns. Both sheet were from different sources and have different data in them, there is overlap for some cells, some don't.

[View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sePyb.png)

Some rows are duplicated, some data is the same, some has data the other does not. Some has different date.

I copied them both into one sheet and sorted them. so now I have:

Each row ("a" from one sheet and "a" from the other) needs combined as they are unique.

How do I combine these sheets/rows? 
Also without losing any data? When it encounters a cell with two different contents, ultimately I’d like it to ask which to keep #1, #2 or both comma separated. However if it just combined the two separated by a comma or slash that would be great.

The sheets are both 98 columns wide. Sheet1 is 14,458 rows and Sheet2 is 11,492 rows so as you can imagine it’s too much to do by hand.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Easiest solution for infrequent use: copy and paste one data set beneath the other. Then select all columns, go to the Data Ribbon > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates. This will remove all rows where everything matches exactly. It will leave all rows where at least 1 data piece is different. Then select the shortened data block and sort as desired.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove duplicates using Excel's Remove Duplicate feature, under the Data tab.

Then use a formula like this :

=IF(A1 <> B2, CONCATENATE(A1, ",", B2),IF(ISBLANK(A1) = TRUE,B2,A1))

To deal with different values. This combines the value in A1 with the value in B1 (with a comma) if they are different, and just takes the value from the non blank cell if they are the same.

Comment: Which added step? Yes, that will remove duplicates, but you also need to concatenate unique values with a comma or slash (per OP's request)

Comment: Ah, I see that now - I think I've misunderstood the question.